# Touchegg touchpad control

Tags: touchpad, workspace, gesture

To make touchegg work, the gestures you do on touchpad are associated with an application. Example: `touchegg.config`

```
<application name="All">
        <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="1" direction="ALL">
            <action type="DRAG_AND_DROP">BUTTON=1</action>
        </gesture>
        <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
            <action type="SEND_KEYS">Super+Control+Right</action>
        </gesture>
```

What I want to do is when I am on the desktop and no application is opened I want to change the workspace by dragging 4 fingers left or right. I tried to write `<application name="None">` but that's not working. Can I do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I use fusuma, which allows you to customize the hotkey that gets sent so you can control either applications or the DE.

https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma